# MYSQL - Returned results GROUP BY and getting the max value from a joined table

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, inner-join, subset

Hard one to title... pretty much at the end of my rope with this hopefully someone will help me. There are similar questions posted but few seem to deal with joined tables / my limited skills in this area.

I have 2 tables - clients and interviews.

--clients--
id / first_name / surname / practitioner_id / status

--interviews--
id / client_id / planned_review_date

My aim is to do the seemingly simple task of returning a list of upcoming interview dates for the currently logged in practitioner.

I can return all the dates with the below code -

```
        SELECT c.id, 
              c.first_name, 
               c.surname,
               i.planned_review_date,
               i.id AS IntID
        FROM clients AS c
        INNER JOIN interviews AS i
        ON c.id=i.client_id
        WHERE c.practitioner_id = 18
        AND c.status <> 'Archived' 
        ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

This gives me something like -

```
id  first_name  surname     planned_review_date     IntID 
20  Terry       Stamp       2016-04-01 00:00:00     62
20  Terry       Stamp       2016-03-01 00:00:00     61
19  Iam         More        2016-07-01 15:47:57     60
19  Iam         More        2016-08-20 00:00:00     59
10  Steve       Powers      2016-04-20 00:00:00     58
10  Steve       Powers      2015-03-20 00:00:00     57
```

I need only one date to show per client for their next interview I grouped them with

```
GROUP BY c.id
```

Which leads to a cut down list as I expect, one row per client. However the actual returned date is not the newest date (ie the one associates with the highest i.id for that client). I understand this is due to a limitation with the way GROUP BY works but I cannot for the life of me get subquerys to work in order to sort it beforehand.

```
id  first_name  surname        planned_review_date  IntID 
20  Terry       Stamp          2016-03-01 00:00:00  61
19  Iam         More           2016-08-20 00:00:00  59
10  Steve       Powers         2016-04-20 00:00:00  58
```

I require the above details but with the IntID's of 62,60 and 58. ie what i need returned is  -

```
id  first_name  surname     planned_review_date     IntID 
20  Terry       Stamp       2016-04-01 00:00:00     62 
19  Iam         More        2016-07-01 15:47:57     60
10  Steve       Powers      2016-04-20 00:00:00     58
```

As a note - the newest date under i.planned_review_date wont always be the "newest", we can assume the date tied to the highest i.id for that client will be the relevant newest date as it is the input review date on the most recent interview.

I know about max() but have not been able to implement it in a way that it returns the max(i.id) for the associated client as opposed to giving me the flat max - 62 in this case. I suspect this is the crux of what the subquery should handle.

Ive been at this a good while, creating what turned out to be more complex code versions of the above. Not my area having inherited this project but having to make the best of it. Im sure ive been close in my many, many tries but am having to put up the white flag - can someone help?

edit - updated as i had some of the returned fields in wrong order

Comment: you need two queries. one to get the ids/relevant fields, and another one to join against to select the rest of the records the child query found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive a subset which just contains the max date for each client ID and then join that back to your query as such:  Assuming planned_Review_date is the "newest" data you're looking for.

The subquery returns the Client_ID and max planned date. By inner joining this back to your base set we limit that set to ONLY be for records with that max date.

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.first_name, 
       c.surname,
       i.planned_review_date,
       i.id AS IntID
FROM clients AS c
INNER JOIN interviews AS i
  ON c.id=i.client_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT Client_ID, max(Planned_review_Date) MD 
            FROM interviews    
            GROUP BY client_ID) I2
     on I2.Client_ID = I.Client_ID 
    and I2.MD = I.Planned_Review_Date
WHERE c.practitioner_id = 18
  AND c.status <> 'Archived' 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: This appears to be correct. Im going to test it on larger dataset through the day but it is working good on the small test I have, I assume it will be fine on larger. Will report back and close question down. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!.  in MySQl this is the only approach I'm aware of, In other RDBMS you could use window functions to identify the max date and limit based on it.  such as `max(planned_review_date) over (partition by Client_ID))` and then use that value as a comparison to each date to only return the max.